# SFTP with Password VIA Shell Script

Tags: shell, sftp

Is it possible to pass SFTP USER/PASS to a server in an automated script that will log in and retrieve a file?

I know that KEY PAIRS are the recommended method but assume thats not possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case you use a key based authorization so you don't need to enter any credentials.

For doing that create a key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And copy it to the target system:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote-system
```

Now you can login to the system without a password.

If your problem is the missing `ssh-copy-id` command try this here:

```
cat ~/.ssh/*.pub | ssh user@remote-system 'umask 077; cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: thank you but I stated in my question key pairs is not an option at this time. Assume the server admin has a policy not to use key pairs.